# RxJava HashMap Transformation

Tags: java, android, hashmap, transformation, rx-java

Supposing i have the following data structure:

```
Map<String, ObjectA> map;
```

and the ObjectA:

```
class ObjectA {
   String a;
   String b;
   int c;    
}
```

My final goal is to return just:

```
Map<String, String>
```

In which the first String is the same as the original, and the second String is the 'String a'. What transformations do i need to accomplish this?

If this was a list, i would have used Observable.from(), take what i want from the single items and then at the end join them together with toList(). But this is a map and i have never nor do i know how to perform iteration over maps in RxJava. Any help would be appreciated

Edit. I know i can do this using Observable.create and use the normal Java/way of doing it like the first answer states. What i really want to know is if there are any Rx Operators that allow me to do that, like Observable.from, flatMap and toList, if i was transforming lists

Comment: I don't understand the question. How would you do it in plan Java?

Comment: I would do exactly as the first comment states. But i am looking for the right RxJava Operators to do so if there are any.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Observable.just(map)
        .map(stringObjectAMap -> stringObjectAMap.entrySet())
        .flatMapIterable(entries -> entries)
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue().a))
        .toMap(e -> e)
        .subscribe(m -> {
            //do something with map
        });
```

Comment: Is it possible to merge the flatMapIterable and map sections ( e.g. .flatMapIterable(stringObjectAMap -> stringObjectAMap.entrySet())? Also would the same hold for the subsequent map / toMap operators?

Comment: @JohnMcClean, yes, you are right. But I like to isolate every step for clarity. It helps me to understand how data streams are transforms

Comment: `.flatMapIterable(entries -> entries)` can be replaced with `.flatMap(Observable::from)`

Comment: `.map(stringObjectAMap -> stringObjectAMap.entrySet()).flatMapIterable(entries -> entries)`                                                                      
 can be replaced with `.flattenAsObservable(Map::entrySet)`

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using java8 streams:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

public class Example {
    public void method() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("a", 4);
            put("b", new Object());
            put("c", 'o');
        }};

        Map<String, String> stringMap = map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().toString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: hey. thank you for your kind answer :p as stated in the question, im looking for the Rx-way, using rx operators. I know how to do it the java-way